# How to load appsettings.Development.json from project within XUnit tests

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

My tests use HttpClient.  So I have built a helper method init the client in the constructor of all of my test files.

I initially tried using AppContext.BaseDirectory to get the base directory for the project that I was trying to test.  The problem is that its not picking up the correct project name so its loading the appsettings.Development.json from a different project causing the tests to fail.   I ended up hard coding the project dir.

I cant figure out how I can force it to load the appsettings.Development.json from the project I want to test.

```
 public static HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {

        // projectDir one, loads tests project.
        // var projectDir = AppContext.BaseDirectory;

      
       var projectDir = @"C:\Work\Src\Application\bin\Debug\net5.0";
        
        var server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(projectDir)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json")
                .Build()
            )
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
        );
        return server.CreateClient();
    }
```

The main issue being that it cant load the settings for RabbitMQ which come from the appsettings.Development.json file.

```
 // Load RabbitMQ config.
 var serviceClientSettingsConfig = Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMq");
 services.Configure<RabbitMqConfiguration>(serviceClientSettingsConfig);
```

Note: I plan to mock this latter but for now my client needs to see end to end tests working.

Comment: Can't you configure settings in the startup so you could inject them in your test class?

Comment: They are that's the problem the settings aren't loaded because it cant grab the correct appsettings.Development.json.   Check edit issue is with the configuration of RabbitMQ in the startup.